can't add active directory users intermittently
I have an Active Directory account running on Windows Server 2019. I have about 120 Windows computers connected to it. About half are Surface Laptop Gos and the other half are Lenovo Yogas mostly running windows 11 but a few running windows 10. The error described below takes place on both kinds of computers and both operating systems.
When I join a computer using the wizard and put in the domain administrator account and password, it will ask to add the domain administrator account as a user, and I will tell it to add it as an administrative user to the local computer.
About one in 10 times on average, the add user wizard will say "there was a problem," and I will have to click 'skip' on the add user wizard. It will still join the domain, but the domain administrator user will not be added to the computer. I will usually then try to add the domain administrator user after disconnecting from the network and reconnecting. Sometimes this works, but the rest of the time it will still not add the user, this time saying, "there was an error."
This is an intermittent problem. Not only does it not happen on most computers, but it doesn't happen consistently on the same computer. When I fail to add the user and put the computer away for a bit then come back and try to add the domain user again, usually it will work, but occasionally it still won't.
When I look at the event viewer after the failed attempt to add the user, I will see the error marked as "Event 12, AppModel-State" taking place at about the time I tried to add it. The full message is something like "Failure to write an application setting for package Microsoft.Surfacehub.... Error code -2147023878." But I can't confirm this event is connected to the failed addition of the user.
What is going on, and how can I prevent this?
Alternately: What logs can I look at to find more information about what's causing this error?
UPDATE: I have learned the error that is leading to this but haven't figured out how to fix it. When I use the commandline method of adding the user:
net localgroup Administrators /add domain\username

Which I got from this stack overflow question I got the error The trust relationship between this workstation and the primary domain failed.
From this question I tried the solution of resetting the trust relationship:
Reset-ComputerMachinePassword -Server DomainControllerNameOrIP -Credential Domain\AdminAccountName

However, it did not fix the trust relationship.

Hi @Run5k, you're right, thank you.

This question is similar to: can't add active directory users intermittently. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Error code -2147023878 is a generic COM error generated when software tries to do something illegal on a registry key (like change it after it's been marked for deletion). It's most likely a bug with the wizard doing things in the wrong order, if it's related at all.

Something else you can try is using powershell to do what the wizard is failing on, which should at least generate a better error message. Open powershell as administrator, and run these commands, updating the names:
# join the computer to the domain (everything other than -DomainName is optional):
Add-Computer -DomainName 'my.domain.name' -Credential 'MYDOMAIN\AdminUser' -OUPath 'OU=Laptops,DC=my,DC=domain,DC=com'

# add a domain user as a local administrator
Add-LocalGroupMember -Group 'Administrators' -Member 'MYDOMAIN\AdminUser'


Since you're running a windows domain, you can also try using Group Policy to add that domain user automatically to computers in the domain. You can find that option under: Computer Configuration -> Policies -> Windows Settings -> Security Settings -> Restricted Groups

Thanks for the Powershell commands, they did work. I haven't marked this as a solution because I don't yet know for now if they will have the same intermittent failure as using the wizard but if they keep working and don't have that problem I'll mark this as solved.
